# memory usage of Ignite Server

Tags: memory-management, ignite

My ignite server is running on a machine with 64G memory.The total cache occupies about 20G memory(off-heap memory, I get this information using the `cache -a` command after staring `ignitevisorcmd.sh`), but when I run the `top` command to see the memory usage, it looks that this process occupied 50G memory, I would ask how could this happen?

`PID   USER  PR  NI  VIRT   RES  SHR  S %CPU %MEM TIME+       COMMAND
10001 root  20  0   63.1G  51G  15m  S 70%  80%  400:57.38   java`

Comment: Could someone take a look? I am wondering how to know how much memory an ignite server takes besides the cache.

Comment: What is your offheap configuration and what is heap usage?

Comment: Thanks @Mitya for the reply. I only use off heap. The configuration is as followings: `cacheConfig.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
 cacheConfig.setBackups(0);     cacheConfig.setMemoryMode(CacheMemoryMode.OFFHEAP_TIERED);
        cacheConfig.setOffHeapMaxMemory(0);
        cacheConfig.setOffHeapMaxMemory(48*1024*1024*1024);`

Comment: Tom, could you check what is the size of heap and analyze heap dump? For example, with VisualVM. If you have some processing logic, keep in mind that any access to offheap entry will load it to heap. Also there was a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3339) fixed in 1.7 release.

Comment: Thanks @MityaXMitya for the reply. I am using Ignite 1.8. One quick question per your comment: `any access to offheap entry will load it to heap`. If my data is 20G on off heap, then when I do a sql `select *`against the cache, then all the entries will be brought to on heap that will also occupy about 20G on heap memory?

Comment: No, you will get QueryCursor that iterates over offheap entries according to request, and entry will be loaded to heap only on next() method call. If you call getAll() then all entries will be copied to heap.

Comment: Yes...I overlooked that..Thanks @MityaXMitya

Answer (score 1):

The difference is consumed by JVM. This can be a lot of things - overhead provided by Ignite (any Java application uses heap memory, Ignite only moves actual data to off-heap), objects produced by data processing (e.g. queries), garbage that will be eventually collected by GC, etc. For deeper understanding you should take a heap dump and analyze what is consuming your heap memory.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin, I will do more investigation.